# webpage, jquery passing value lose : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, onclick

I'm trying to save the edited data while click "send message" button

here is the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting
> 'innerHTML')

seems saying "itemValue" is none, but I'm not sure where get problem?

```
  <script>
    var storedItem = localStorage.getItem("storedItem");
    
    function save() {
      var itemValue = document.getElementById("input_edit_data").value;
      localStorage.setItem("storedItem", itemValue);
      document.getElementById("savedText").innerHTML = itemValue;
      console.log("storedItem", storedItem);
    }
  </script>



  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">device_id:</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="field1" class="col-form-label">group:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_data">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="field2" class="col-form-label">id :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_data">
            </div>

       


            <!-- End of additional form fields -->
            
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()">Send message</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm new to this community, thinking of everyone is excellent experts, maybe I can get a cool feedback, thanks

---

- the full version of code, in case needed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Meta tags and other head elements -->
  <title>Static Template</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
   
</head>
<body>

  
  
  </html>

  <div id="app"></div>
  <table id="example" class="display"></table>

  <!-- JavaScript libraries -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var storedItem = localStorage.getItem("storedItem");
    
    function save() {
      var itemValue = document.getElementById("input_edit_data").value;
      localStorage.setItem("storedItem", itemValue);
      document.getElementById("savedText").innerHTML = itemValue;
      console.log("storedItem", storedItem);
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

      var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://192.168.01.10:8000/api/item_status",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA", response.ipcs);
            return response.ipcs
          }
        },
        columns: [
          {
            data: null,
            title: "ACTION",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit-btn" data-id="' + row.device_id + '">Edit</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-btn" data-id="' + row.device_id + '">Delete</button>';
            }
          },
          {
            data: null,
            title: "edit",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return'<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Edit</button>   ';
            }
          },

          {
            data: null,
            title: "edit_new",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever=" ">edit_new</button>';
            }
          },
          
          { data: "device_id", title: "device_id" },
          { data: "device_id", title: "device_id" },
          { data: "name", title: "name" },
          { data: "group", title: "group" },
          { data: "ip", title: "ip" },

        ]
      });


      table.draw()
  

      var rowData; 

      $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function (event) {  


        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        rowData = data;
  
        console.log("GET edit DATA", data)        

      });

      
      $(function(){
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

          var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
          var recipient = button.data('whatever');
         
          var data = rowData;
          
          var modal = $(this);
          modal.find('.modal-title').text('Update data ' + recipient);
          var inputFields = modal.find('.modal-body input');
          var keys = Object.keys(data);
          for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
            var inputValue = data[keys[i]];
            $(inputFields[i]).val(inputValue);
          }
        });
      });
  


      function editRow_website(id){
        
   
            
        var device_id=document.getElementById("device_id"+id);  
        var name=document.getElementById("name"+id);  
        var group=document.getElementById("group"+id);
        var ip=document.getElementById("ip"+id);

        
        let getEditData = {
          "device_id": device_id,
          "email_data": name,
          "address_data": group,
          "name_data": ip,
        }

        document.getElementById("#editid input").value = device_id
       

        
      }
      
 
      $(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function (event) {  
        var id = $(this).data('id')
        
        console.log("GET DLETE ID", id)

        confirmDelete(id) 
      });

      function deleteData(id) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://192.168.01.10:8000/api/item_status="+ id,
          type:'DELETE',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken  
          },
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }

        }).then(res => console.log("RES", res));  
      }


      function editRow(id) {



        console.log("EDIT", getFinalData);

      }

      function confirmDelete(id) {
        if (confirm("sure to delete this row？")== true) {
          var table = $("#example").DataTable();
          var row = table.row($(this).closest('tr'));
          deleteData(id);

          if (row.length > 0) {
            row.remove().draw();
            console.log("Delete row with id:", id);
          }
        } else{
          none
        }

      }
    });
  </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <div class ="table-title">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add New</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">device_id:</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="field1" class="col-form-label">group:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_data">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="field2" class="col-form-label">id :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_edit_data">
            </div>

                   
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()">Send message</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>






  <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
          $('.modalTextInput').val('');
          let btn = $(e.relatedTarget); // e.related here is the element that opened the modal, specifically the row button
          let id = btn.data('id'); // this is how you get the of any `data` attribute of an element
          $('.saveEdit').data('id', id); // then pass it to the button inside the modal
        })
      
        $('.saveEdit').on('click', function() {
          let id = $(this).data('id'); // the rest is just the same
          saveNote(id);
          $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle'); // this is to close the modal after clicking the modal button
        })
      })
      
      function saveNote(id) {
        let text = $('.modalTextInput').val();
        $('.recentNote').data('note', text);
        console.log($('.recentNote').data('note'));
        console.log(text + ' --> ' + id);
      }

    
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mostly common error for elements that either do not exist or cannot be found. This happens if the script is executed before the element is read. YOu should not spread multiple scripts across the entire page but in one place. Make sure that the DOM array completely exists before referencing an element.

Comment: PS Your markup is invalid. You close `</html>` right at the start of the body. This can cause unintended behavior such as ending the document there.

Comment: _"seems saying "itemValue" is none"_ - no it doesn't, it says that what you are trying to use innerHTML _on_, is null. `document.getElementById("savedText").innerHTML = ...` - so where is that element with the ID `savedText`? I don't see any in the code you have shown.

Comment: for `</html>`, I will correct, but for ID `document.getElementById("savedText").innerHTML = ..` how to correct these though?

Comment: "the full version of code, in case needed" — That HTML doesn't have an element with `id="savedText"` so what you do expect `document.getElementById("savedText").innerHTML = ..` to do?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`document.getElementById("savedText")` returns `null`, so it does not have an `innerHTML` to refer to.

You can change

```
document.getElementById("savedText").innerHTML = itemValue;
```

to

```
let savedText = document.getElementById("savedText");
if (savedText) {
    savedText.innerHTML = itemValue;
}
```

That would check whether the element was found and only set its `innerHTML` if it exists to prevent the error from occurring.

But your element is missing for a reason and you will need to find out why. You either do not have such an element at all, which seems to be the case based on the code you have shared, where no such tag exists, or it was not loaded when your Javascript evaluates.

Comment: I would be glad to see the reason of the downvote. This answer seems to be correct to me.

Comment: For me because you do not solve the actual issue. Your answer is just to bypass the error message on the cost by creating new issues instead of solving the actual issue (that this specific element does not exist in his code, that he uses the same Ids multiple times and that some of his scrips are executed before the element exists in the actual DOM).

Comment: @tacoshy thanks for providing reasons for the down-vote. If you read my answer to the end, you will see the last paragraph where it is stated that "But your element is missing for a reason and you will need to find out why. You either do not have such an element at all, which seems to be the case based on the code you have shared, where no such tag exists, or it was not loaded when your Javascript evaluates.". As a result, I cannot agree with your reason, given the fact that I make it very clear that there is an issue underlying which needs to be resolved...

Comment: @tacoshy ... and I also clarify what the possible issues are. As about having multiple ids as being a potential cause of this behavior, that can be excluded, see https://jsfiddle.net/0uao2pgf/. It is incorrect to use the same id multiple times indeed, but `getElementById` will not yield `null` for an input that is present multiple times in the structure.

Comment: thanks for all the ways you guys helping, at least I could work on a bit